# Looping a map and updating key values in Elixir

Tags: loops, dictionary, increment, elixir

```
def sort(someString) do

    countSubstring = fn(_, "") -> 0
             (str, sub) -> length(String.split(str, sub)) - 1 end

    someMap = %{:a => 0, :b => 0, :c => 0, :d => 0}

    def loopMap(aMap, n) when n <= 1 do
        timesKeyFound = countSubstring(someString, aMap[n])
        Map.put_new(aMap, aMap[key], timesKeyFound)
    end

    def loopMap(aMap, n) do
        timesKeyFound = countSubstring(someString, aMap[n])
        Map.put_new(aMap, aMap[key], timesKeyFound)
        loopMap(aMap, n - 1)
    end

    loopMap(someMap, 4) #4 is the number of keys in the map
end
```

What I am trying to do here is to pass a string into the sort module. For example let's pass the string "Hi my name is bob". Once this is passed I create a map with 4 keys: 'a' 'b' 'c' and 'd'. 
Then in my loopMap code I am trying to pass my someMap map and the number of its keys (n) as arguments. Then I search the string for instances of each key and if the key is found I update my map by 1 for each key found.

after I run the loopMap on my someMap i should have an updated map which is:

```
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 0, d: 0}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be:

```
"Hi my name is Bob"
|> String.to_list
|> Enum.reduce(%{a: 0, b: 0}, fn c, acc ->
  case Map.get(acc, :'#{c}') do
    nil -> acc
    n -> Map.put(acc, :'#{c}', n + 1)
  end
end)
```

Comment: What if my map has atoms that aren't single chars such as %{:ob => 0, :ame => 0}?

Comment: For that case, you'd want to reduce over the map keys instead of the characters of the string, and then use a regex and get the number of matches for that substring once for each key.